# How to add an image to custom button

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I have very simple questions, How to add an image in custom button?

```
   <com.example.KeyButton 
                android:id="@+id/custombutton" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"     />
```

Comment: use `android:background`

Comment: Same way you add image on `ImageView` `android:background="@drawable/image".

Comment: thanx for your reply, but i like the view like image button have png image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Tag `android:background="@drawable/your_image"`

```
<com.example.KeyButton 
            android:id="@+id/custombutton" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [android:backgroud](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground) to add image.

```
<com.example.KeyButton 
android:id="@+id/custombutton" 
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:background"@drawable/image"   /> //here will be your image.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/yourImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And put "your_image" in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

put image of button in drawble folder and put this code in your xml file....

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_your_btn_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/set_alarm_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use programmatically the methods :

```
setBackground(Color c); and
setBackground(Drawable d);
setBackgroundResource(int resId);
```

otherwise, you can use the xml way like stated above